How to find kernel of this homomorphism?

The Problem:
Find the kernel of the following homomorphism:
$f:\mathbb{G}→\mathbb{Z}/2$, where $\mathbb{G}$ is the quaternion group and $f(A)= 0̅ ,f(B)=1̅ $

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{-1}
 & 0 \\
0 & -\sqrt{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
 $and$ 
 B = \begin{bmatrix}
0
 & \sqrt{-1} \\
\sqrt{-1} & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$
(All elements of Quaternion Group:$\begin{bmatrix}
1
 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$
$\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{-1}
 & 0 \\
0 & -\sqrt{-1}
\end{bmatrix}$
$
\begin{bmatrix}
0
 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$
$
\begin{bmatrix}
0
 & \sqrt{-1} \\
\sqrt{-1} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$
$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1
 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$
$
\begin{bmatrix}
-\sqrt{-1}
 & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{-1}
\end{bmatrix}$
$
\begin{bmatrix}
0
 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$
$
\begin{bmatrix}
0
 & -\sqrt{-1} \\
-\sqrt{-1} & 0
\end{bmatrix}
)$
What did I think? and Where am I stuck?
First, I want to say that I am learning Algebra. And if we look at the identity element of $\mathbb{Z}/2$, we will find 0̅. So matrix $A$ is an element of $Ker(f)$. And I wrote $Ker(f)={A}$. Is it true? Am I missing other elements (if it exists)?

Since the kernel is a subgroup, and ${A}$ is not a subgroup (it does not include the identity), then it is certainly false that the kernel of $f$ is the set ${A}$.

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial. It is a bit shorter to write $i$ for $\sqrt{-1}$.

Since the group has order 8 and the homomorphism is surjective, therefore the kernel should be a subgroup of order 4. In an elementary manner, one can argue that since $A$ is in the kernel (which is a subgroup), hence the element $A^2 = -I$ should also be in the kernel, and thus, so should the element $-A$ be.  Thus kernel = $\{ \pm I, \pm A\}$.

You can rewrite the group as $G = { \pm I, \pm A, \pm B, \pm AB }$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix and $A^2 = B^2 = (AB)^2 = -I$).  Then everything becomes simpler and easier to understand /calculate.

Thank you so much!

The homomorphism is not trivial since $f(B)\ne0.$
Therefore the kernel has order $4$ ($f$ is surjective).
There's $3$ subgroups of order $4.$
Since $A$ is in the kernel and has order four ($A^2=-1$), the kernel is the cyclic group generated by $A.$
